# Is it possible to replace a cross apply with a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I am reverse engineering some legacy SQL algorithms to move to apache spark.

I have encountered a across apply which I understand is TSQL specific and there is no direct equivalent in ANSII or Spark SQL.

The sanitized algorithm is:

```
SELECT
        Id_P ,
        Monthindex     ,
        (
                SELECT
                        100 * (STDEV(ResEligible.num_valid) / AVG(ResEligible.num_valid)) AS Pre_Coef_Var
                FROM
                        tbl_p a CROSS APPLY
                        (
                                SELECT
                                        e.Monthindex ,
                                        e.num AS num_valid
                                FROM
                                        dbo.tbl_p e
                                WHERE
                                        e.Monthindex     = a.MonthIndex
                                AND     e.Id_P = a.Id_P

                                UNION ALL

                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                        B1.[MonthIndex       ] ,
                                        Tr.num AS num_valid
                                FROM
                                        #tbl_pr B1
                                INNER JOIN
                                        #tbl_pr B2
                                ON
                                        B1.[Id_P] = B2.[Id_P]
                                AND     B2.Rang - B1.Rang BETWEEN 0 AND     2
                                INNER JOIN
                                        dbo.tbl_p Tr
                                ON
                                        Tr.Id_P = B1.Id_P
                                AND     Tr.Monthindex     = B1.Monthindex
                                WHERE
                                        a.Id_P = B1.[Id_P]
                                AND     B2.[MonthIndex]  =
                                        (
                                                SELECT
                                                        MAX([MonthIndex])
                                                FROM
                                                        #tbl_pr
                                                WHERE
                                                        [MonthIndex]     < a.MonthIndex
                                                AND     [Id_P] = a.Id_P) ) AS ResEligible
                WHERE
                        a.Id_P = result.Id_P
                AND     a.MonthIndex     = result.MonthIndex) AS Coeff
FROM
        tbl_p AS result
WHERE
        1          = 1
AND     MonthIndex = @CurrentMonth
GROUP BY
        Id_P ,
        Monthindex) AS CC
```

so for every row in alias b we cross apply to the inner queries.

Is it possible to re-write the cross apply in terms of join operations (or otherwise) so I can re-implement in spark sql?

Cheers

Terry

Comment: Probably. An `APPLY` doesn't have an `ON` where as a `JOIN` does (apart from a `CROSS JOIN`), so you would need to move parts of the clauses, but we don't have the "meat" of your query to help you here.

Comment: *"but we don't have the "meat" of your query to help you here. "* i think @Larnu meant to tell here [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I assume that `Spark` has troubles with the `cross apply` ? Maybe a simple solution could be to create a `View` that holds this query, and then just do `select col1, ... from myView` Thus effective hide the cross apply from spark

Comment: Spark does not support cross apply

Comment: Exa,ple updated to show example cross apply expression

Comment: what does alias `a` relate to?  looking at your sample, the cross apply is not even needed

Comment: Providing valid sample SQL (without Syntax errors) is really important too. :)

Comment: If you apply expression uses regular selects, should be easy. If it uses syntax like "TOP n / ORDER BY" then it will be much harder.

Comment: Sorry about the typos - I was trying to anonymize my sample code.

Comment: OK - I have sanitized the actual algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could rewrite your query as the below:

```
SELECT T1.col1,
       T1.col2,
       sq.col3Sum
FROM tbl1 T1
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(T1sq.Col3) AS col3Sum
                 FROM tbl1 T1sq
                     JOIN tbl2 T2 ON T1sq.Col1 = T2.Col2
                     JOIN tbl3 T3 ON T2.col1 = T3.Col1) sq;
```

*Seems odd, however, that there was no `JOIN` criteria between the 2 references to `tbl1`.*